# Why is the following function doing `greet({ name = 'Rauno' } = {})` instead of `greet(name = 'Rauno')`?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, default-value

```
function greet({ name = 'Rauno' } = {}) {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
}
 
greet() // Hi Rauno!
greet({ name: 'Larry' }) // Hi Larry!
```

Although, I understand the basic functionality here... I don't understand what the need was to do `greet({ name = 'Rauno' } = {})` instead of `greet(name = 'Rauno')`. Don't they achieve the same result? So, why?

Comment: well its a mixture about default parameter values and object destructuring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the short answer is no.
assume you have your function and call it like below:

```
function greet({ name = 'Rauno' }) {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
}

greet(); // throws reference error
```

you are passing nothing(implicitly `undefined`) as the first argument. so javascript fails when it tries to access `undefined.name` and throws reference error. because `undefined` is not an object and has not a name property. so you should set a default value for the argument to cover `undefined` cases. then javascript tries to retrieve `{}.name`, it's `undefined` and the default value for name is retrieved(Rauno in your case).

Answer (score 1):

In the given codeblock, the `greet` function accepts an object with a property of "name". See how the call looks: `greet({ name: 'Larry' }) // Hi Larry!`

If you wrote `function greet(name = "Rauno") { /***/ }` that function would accept a single string parameter, so you would call that like `greet("@Grateful");`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it definitely helped me understand other answers better. Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to select multiple answers.